# Firebase notification stopped after using it for a while (react-native-fcm)

Tags: react-native-fcm

Thank you in advance.
After I fully implemented react-native-fcm, everything was working perfectly for the notification. But after a while the notification stopped coming in after some weeks. The device (android phone) stopped receiving notification.
Please I'm not sure how to get it working again. Please help me

//////////////

const API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

class FirebaseClient {

async send(body, type) {

```
let headers = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "keyishere"
});

try {
  let response = await fetch(API_URL, { method: "POST", headers, body });
  console.log("body of push notification");
  console.log(body);
  console.log("resss");
  console.log(response);
  try {
    response = await response.json();
    console.log("notification Response");
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.success) {
      console.log("Failed to send notification, check error loggggggg");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Failed to send notification, check error log");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err && err.message);
}
```

}
}

let firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient();

export default firebaseClient;

```
    FCM.requestPermissions();

    FCM.enableDirectChannel();

    registerAppListener(this.props.navigation);

    FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => {
      if (notif.opened_from_tray) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("Notification Home");
          console.log(notif.body);

          console.log(notif.deliveryRequestId);
          deliveryId = notif.deliveryRequestId;

          // if (notif.targetScreen == "HomePage") {
          //   this.props.navigation.push("HomePage");
          // }
          // this._onRefresh(notif.body);
        }, 500);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have done.

Comment: @Kishan Bharda thanks for your interest to assist me. I have added some code as requested.